# SVG not showing up in any browser

Tags: html, css, svg

I downloaded this [flag-icon-css](http://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/) to use on a site I'm working on.

I can see the US flag fine locally here from the screen shot:
[image]
But the flag does not show up live in any browser. I cannot figure out what I am missing. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong? This is the first time I'm using SVG so forgive me, I am learning.

[Live html page is here.](http://hauppauge.com/responsive/index-fluid.htm)

[CSS is here](http://hauppauge.com/responsive/flag-icon-css-master/css/flag-icon.css)

Thank You!

Comment: the path isn't correct. it's returning 404 in the svg request

Comment: http://hauppauge.com/responsive/flag-icon-css-master/flags/4x3/us.svgyou are talking about this right? And this I can't figure out, I cannot see this live, but when I view this path locally I see the image fine.Maybe I should see if there are any issues with the hosting server?

Comment: Do you have the svg and all the folders in the live version ?

Comment: Yes I do, I see it on the sever but it is just not showing up live, only locally

Comment: check if the path is equal to the one in the server .. because if it's in the server, the path is incorrect to find it. being an `svg` has nothing to do with it, because the `img` tag reads `svgs` the same way, except for some browsers like IE9

Comment: with a really quick check there's a localhost path on a javascript file commented as "svg flag" line 319 -- "http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"